# Oracle или SQL, резервируют память под CLOB?

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Если у меня есть таблица:

```
id | CLOB          | Title
1  | много текста..| Золотая рыбка  
2  | null          | Картинки
```

и допустим, в половине случаев, запись в таблице не имеет текста в поле `CLOB`. Что будет с выделенной памятью? С `fulltext` поиском? Это крайне негативная ситуация, или за кулисами `Oracle` все красиво сделает?
Если кто-то знает, благодарю заранее :-)

Comment: NULL никогда не сохраняется, неважно, какого типа колонка.

Answer (score 0):

если вы поставите поле с CLOB последней колонкой в таблице, её пустые значения не будут совсем занимать места на диске. если оставите как сейчас - пустые значения будут занимать 1 байт

работа именно с ОПЕРАТИВНОЙ ПАМЯТЬЮ будет эффективна или нет в зависимости от того, прочитаете ли вы [теорию о работе с LOB'ами](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_intro.htm) или нет. например, забудьте о работе с LOB'ами как со строками - пользуйтесь вместо этого пакетом [DBMS_LOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66622)